# star wars api promises looping javascript

Tags: javascript, axios

I am attempting to use a for loop to go through all the promises which I believe according to my console log are the movies objects from swapi. My for loop does not at all iterate through the promise array. The for loop with index j is never reached and I do not understand why. Is there a syntax error I'm not seeing or is there a paradigm about axios and promise that I am ignoring?

```
enter code here       
    let length = data.films.length
    let promises = [];
            for(let i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                    promises.push(axios.get(data.films[i]));
            }

            Promise.all(promises).then(function (value){

                    moviesList=value
                    console.log(moviesList)
                    document.getElementById("movies0").innerHTML =value[0].data.title
                    for(var j=0; j <5; j++)
                    {
                            console.log("movies"+j)
                            document.getElementById("movies"+j).innerHTML = value[j].data.title
                    }

            })
```

Comment: Looks fine, assuming `value` contains an object/array that matches the code you are using to iterate over it and said elements with said id's exist.

Comment: Is data defined in the code before this? When I run it in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1vy52wex/1/) it throws an Uncaught ReferenceError at window.onload. Hope that helps.